# High Voltage PMOS devices availability

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, semiconductors, pmos

Generic question for experts well versed in semiconductor device physics. Most of the high voltage power switching devices seen are N-Channel (Silicon and Silicon Carbide) with varying ratings. Is there a theoretical limit to the breakdown voltage of P-channel power MOSFETS? The design in question is for a pulsed 1.2kV supply. Currently due to device availability, options are restricted to using a NMOS on the return line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, it is not due to breakdown strength limits but because high voltage switchers usually are also high power switchers and for those, efficiency is a very strong design goal. NMOS are simply more efficient than PMOS due to higher charge carrier mobility of electrons compared to holes in Si and SiC.

Since the drift zone is anyway lightly doped for high voltage MOSFETs, I see no reason why it couldn't be realized with either polarity in principle.